# monotouch (xamarin|android) equivalent of setTimeout and setInterval

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am probably taking the wrong approach here, I come from the JS async programming.

Is there an equivalent to run a `delegate` or a lambda after a number of milliseconds?

I want to trigger a function after some period of time after a click event has happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is.
An equivalent to setTimeout: start a new thread (too prevent blocking the main thread) and pause that thread:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    Thread.Sleep(500); // delay execution for 500 ms
    // more code
});
```

If you want to set an interval, look at `System.Threading.Timers`.

And remember, if you want to interact with the user interface from within your `Task` or `Timer`, use `InvokeOnMainThread(...)`!

Comment: Thanks, good references, I will look more into so I don't endup bloating things, as in JS the timeouts are really cheap

Comment: Didn't work as expected.. is the containing ("closure") scope not available? https://gist.github.com/4405026

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're trying to update the UI from a background thread which is not allowed. Try replacing the call to SwitchLayoutA() with RunOnUiThread(() => SwitchLayoutA());

Comment: Try/Use Greg's suggestion. RunOnUiThread is the Android/MonoDroid equivalent of InvokeOnMainThread, which is available on iOS/MonoTouch.

Comment: Be careful using that thread.sleep code - in future async/await use it could block the ui thread. IMO better to use Task.Delay instead - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay.aspx

Comment: I guess this is more enough info for me to digest, thanks a lot guys!